# ITHit WebDAV - Office not available message showing when Office is installed

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

We have implemented the IT Hit WebDAV sever on our website and are currently testing it before purchasing.

One of the tests we have done is test it in different browsers and operating systems. We have found that in Vista and the Latest Chrome it shows the message Microsoft Office not available when office is installed and working and the page works in other browser/OS combinations.

We are using the JavaScript from IT Hit which has not been changed. Below is the code (TypeScript Code) I have used on the button:

```
//Gets an instance of ITHIT DocManager
var oNs = ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager;
if (oNs.IsMicrosoftOfficeAvailable()) {
    oNs.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(responseData.documentUrl);
} else {
    editBtn.html(officeNotAvailableLang);
}
```

**Before Clicking Edit**
[image: Before clicking edit]

**Office not available error**
[image: Office not available error]

**Office is installed on the machine**
[image: Office is installed]

Is this a known issue and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because the Microsoft Office plugin is disabled in your web browser for some reason. To enable the plugin:

- **In case of Google Chrome** plugins could be found here:
  chrome://plugins:
  [image]
- **In case of FireFox** they are in Options Menu -> Addons -> Plugins tab:
  [image]
- **In case of IE** they are under Tools Menu -> Manage Add-ons. Make sure
  you select 'All add-ons' in Show dropdown:
  [image]