# Unable to edit MS 2010 doc on IT Hit Ajax File Browser Demo

Tags: ms-word, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I went to the example page:
http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/#http://www.ajaxfilebrowser.com/User9237b4f/

I have created a file using `Microsoft Word 2010 (14.0.7145.5001) SP2 MSO (14.0.7145.5000)`. The name of the file is `"This is the End my Friend.doc"`, but I don't know how to attach the to this inquiry.

I am using `Chrome version 41.0.2272.101 m`

I then clicked ‘browse’ on the example and chose to add that file.

I then double clicked the file and received `“Current file cannot be opened for editing”`

Is there any way I can figure out what is causing this issue? Do you have any suggestions for how to debug this issue?

Extremely grateful for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Make sure the Microsoft Office plugin is enabled in your web browser. You can find the details about how to enable it here: [ITHit WebDAV - Office not available message showing when Office is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674684/ithit-webdav-office-not-available-message-showing-when-office-is-installed).
2. Verify that you have all Microsoft Office and Windows updates installed.

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to get the example to work, but when I changed the following line in ITHitWebDavClient.js from

if (!sho.EditDocument(_526)) {

to

if (!sho.EditDocument(_526 + '\0')) {

I was able to get our own code to work in Chrome.